# Does a command-line config tool exist for the Clariion CX

Tags: command-line-interface, storage-area-network, fibre-channel, clariion

On SANs with Mylex RAID controllers there is a command-line utility called mlxcfg that allows one to configure the SAN.  Does such a utility exist for Clariion CX SANs and is it free to use without licensing for Navisphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line utility is called navicli. You can do pretty much anything with it that you can in the normal navisphere gui. I have no idea about the licensing.

Comment: Thanks.  From this I could get hold of EMC and ask a specific question.  The sales guys I talked to were pretty confident that you need to have a navisphere licence to use navcli.

Comment: You can theoretically do anything, but in practice it's such a POS that it takes hours.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it's an integrated or gateway model, but if you have DART datamovers running, you can connect to those through SSH/Putty and manage it from there. Licensing, I believe, is only for the Navisphere / Celerra manager GUI, not the actual usage - though this does not count for replication (you should check with EMC anyways to be certain).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Navisphere ( specifically an Array running Flare presenting the Navisphere user interface) to use the Navisphere CLI but there is no separate license needed in order to install and use them. This is different to PowerPath which needs to be licensed on each host in order to enable its full functionality (load balancing\multipathing..).